# Enable bitcode not in build options

Tags: xcode, bitcode

With XCode 9.2, I am getting the ld error:

ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together

However my Build Options do not contain any entry for Enable Bitcode, and when I try to find it via the search bar I don't find anything.

How can I set ENABLE_BITCODE=NO ?  And, any idea why it doesn't show up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the target "Build settings" then select "All" and "Combined" options. In the search field, type "bitcode" and select the value to "NO"

If the Enable Bitcode option is not on the list of the search results then check if Architecture and BaseSDK options are set up correctly.

Comment: When I type "bitcode" in the search field, it does not find anything.  I had already tried to do just as Adobels suggests.

Comment: 1. Have you verified that your filter for the Build Settings is set to "All" rather than "Basic"? If it is set to "Basic", many of the options won't appear. 2. Is it a new project or created in previous version of the Xcode? 3. What kind of target you are building? iOS, framework or watch ?

Comment: It is a new project created in this version (9.2).  Yes, "All" is set. Target is iOS.  When I type chars in the search field, items successively disappear, which I presume is because it's narrowing things down based on what I have entered.  By the time I get to "bitc", everything has gone from the Build Options screen.

Comment: 1. Create a new clean project and check if you have the "ENABLE_BITCODE" in build options. 2. Do you work with the project file or with a workspace file ? 3. Do you use Cocoapods?

Comment: Your suggestion about creating a new project was very helpful, thanks.  It showed me that I needed to change the Architectures and Base SDK fields.  Then I got the correct set of processors and the Enable Bitcode option was visible.